# Подавление шума изображения Python PIL

Tags: python, pillow

Есть задача.

Имеется изображение. Необходимо внести шум на изображение, а затем, используя алгоритм пороговой фильтрации, очистить зашумлённое изображение.
Под алгоритмом пороговой фильтрации я подразумеваю «Если яркость пикселя превышает среднюю яркость локальной окрестности, тогда яркость пикселя заменяется на среднюю яркость окрестности».
Сам код:

```
from PIL import Image
import random
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

img=Image.open('pic.bmp')
print(img.size)
randomenter=int(input('Enter numpix: '))
for numpix in range(0, randomenter):
    x=random.randint(0,int(img.size[0]-1))
    y=random.randint(0,int(img.size[1]-1))
    r=random.randint(0,255)
    g=random.randint(0,255)
    b=random.randint(0,255)
    img.putpixel((x,y),(r,g,b))
img.show()
img.save("noise.bmp", "BMP")
img2=Image.open("noise.bmp")

width, height = img2.size
pix=img2.load()

for x in range(0,width-1):
    if x-1>0 and x<width:
        for y in range(0,height-1):
            if y-1>0 and y<height:
                local1=(0.3 * pix[x-1,y-1][0]) + (0.59 * pix[x-1,y-1][1]) + (0.11 * pix[x-1,y-1][2])
                local2=(0.3 * pix[x-1,y][0]) + (0.59 * pix[x-1,y][1]) + (0.11 * pix[x-1,y][2])
                local3=(0.3 * pix[x-1,y+1][0]) + (0.59 * pix[x-1,y+1][1]) + (0.11 * pix[x-1,y+1][2])
                local4=(0.3 * pix[x,y-1][0]) + (0.59 * pix[x,y-1][1]) + (0.11 * pix[x,y-1][2])
                LOCAL5=(0.3 * pix[x,y][0]) + (0.59 * pix[x,y][1]) + (0.11 * pix[x,y][2])
                local6=(0.3 * pix[x,y+1][0]) + (0.59 * pix[x,y+1][1]) + (0.11 * pix[x,y+1][2])
                local7=(0.3 * pix[x+1,y-1][0]) + (0.59 * pix[x+1,y-1][1]) + (0.11 * pix[x+1,y-1][2])
                local8=(0.3 * pix[x+1,y][0]) + (0.59 * pix[x+1,y][1]) + (0.11 * pix[x+1,y][2])
                local9=(0.3 * pix[x+1,y+1][0]) + (0.59 * pix[x+1,y+1][1]) + (0.11 * pix[x+1,y+1][2])
                localall=(local1+local2+local3+local4+local6+local7+local8+local9)/8
                localall2=(local1+local2+local3+local4+local6+local7+local8+local9+LOCAL5)/9
                if LOCAL5>=localall:
                    img2.putpixel((x,y),(int(pix[x,y][0]*localall/LOCAL5),int(pix[x,y][1]*localall/LOCAL5),int(pix[x,y][2]*localall/LOCAL5)))
img2.show()
```

Застрял как раз на моменте замены яркости.
Официальная документация не располагает подробностями по этому поводу.
Есть ли вообще как таковое решение этой задачи?
Update
До пикселей добрался. Теперь проблема в том, что изменяются соседние пиксели с изменяемым.

Comment: А что такое яркость пикселя в `RGB` изображении в вашем понимании?

Comment: @Avernial яркость есть какое среднее значение r+g+b, где r,g,b ещё умножены на некоторые коэффициенты. в своей задаче я пока упростил этот момент.

Comment: Попробуйте с изображением как с numpy массивом поработать, используя готовые алгоритмы, [пример кода](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5298884/4279)